# When changing page, Profile not persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using Profile, I want to save some user input in a custom class called `FavoritesObjects` which consists of a `List` of int. After some testing, everything (input, display, functions in `FavoriteObjects`) work well except that whenever the page is changed, the `FavoriteObjects` class assigned to the profile is reset. So whenever the user wants to go back and add an object, this object replace the one already saved.

Code to add object is:

```
public void AddObject(int id, int quantity)
{
    if (ObjectsSaved.Count == 0)
    {
        ObjectsSaved.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(id, quantity));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ObjectsSaved.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ObjectsSaved[i].Item1 == id)
        {
            int quantity_tmp = ObjectsSaved[i].Item2;
            if (quantity > 0)
            {
                ObjectsSaved.RemoveAt(i);
                ObjectsSaved.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(id, quantity + quantity_tmp));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectsSaved.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(id, quantity));
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the input is read, it is saved in the `Profile` with this code:

```
if (id != 0 && quantity > 0)
{        
    if (Profile.ObjectList == null)
    {
        Profile.ObjectList = new ObjectsSaved();
    }

    Profile.ObjectList.AddObject(id, quantity);
}
```

Comment: you need to persist it somewhere - session, sql, etc.

Comment: Where is ObjectsSaved saved? in a database?